# Initialisation of object with init function that provides default values for it's arguments

Tags: swift, constructor, properties

I have the following class:

```
final class A {

    let propertyA: Int
    let propertyB: String
    let propertyC: Double

    init(propertyA: Int = 100, propertyB: String = "propertyB", propertyC: Double = 10.0) {
        self.propertyA = propertyA
        self.propertyB = propertyB
        self.propertyC = propertyC
    }
}
```

As you can see all of it's properties defined as `let` and `init` provides some default values for them. To create an instance of this class I use some non-constant data:

```
var a: Int? = nil // Some random values that can be nil
var b: String? = "b"
var c: Double? = 100.0
```

And here is a very huge code snippet that creates an instance of `A`:

```
let objectA: A
if let a = a, let b = b, let c = c {
    objectA = A(propertyA: a, propertyB: b, propertyC: c)
} else if let a = a, let b = b {
    objectA = A(propertyA: a, propertyB: b)
} else if let b = b, let c = c {
    objectA = A(propertyB: b, propertyC: c)
} else if let a = a, let c = c {
    objectA = A(propertyA: a, propertyC: c)
} else if let a = a {
    objectA = A(propertyA: a)
} else if let b = b {
    objectA = A(propertyB: b)
} else if let c = c {
    objectA = A(propertyC: c)
} else {
    objectA = A()
}
```

The initialisation of `objectA` is too huge, I want to find a way how to make it smaller. However I don't want to declare `A`'s properties as `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test for all nil/non-nil combinations of a, b, c is better done
with a switch-statement:

```
switch (a, b, c) {
case (let a?, let b?, let c?):
    objectA = A(propertyA: a, propertyB: b, propertyC: c)
case (nil, let b?, let c?):
    objectA = A(propertyB: b, propertyC: c)
case (let a?, nil, let c?):
    objectA = A(propertyA: a, propertyC: c)
case (let a?, let b?, nil):
    objectA = A(propertyA: a, propertyB: b)
case (let a?, nil, nil):
    objectA = A(propertyA: a)
case (nil, let b?, nil):
    objectA = A(propertyB: b)
case (nil, nil, let c?):
    objectA = A(propertyC: c)
case(nil, nil, nil):
    objectA = A()
}
```

The main advantage is that the *compiler* checks if the switch is
exhaustive, i.e. all possible combinations are handled exactly once.

However, this does not solve your main issue: the number of combinations
grows exponentially with the number of arguments.

If you define all parameters as *optionals* with a default value of `nil`, and substitute the actual default values in the body of the init function (e.g. with optional chaining):

```
final class A {

    let propertyA: Int
    let propertyB: String
    let propertyC: Double

    init(propertyA: Int? = nil, propertyB: String? = nil, propertyC: Double? = nil) {
        self.propertyA = propertyA ?? 100
        self.propertyB = propertyB ?? "propertyB"
        self.propertyC = propertyC ?? 10.0
    }
}
```

then you can either omit an argument, or pass `nil`, with the same effect.

As a consequence, the code snippet to create an instance of `A` reduces to a single call to the initializer, independent of the number of
arguments:

```
var a: Int? = nil // Some random values that can be nil
var b: String? = "b"
var c: Double? = 100.0

let objectA = A(propertyA: a, propertyB: b, propertyC: c)
```